# How to use persistently use Icicle's multi-buffer search results?

Tags: emacs, icicles

After successfully being about to do [intricate searches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20868492/1309352) using Icicles. I now have a problem with being about to use those results.

I found it pretty convenient in `multi-occur-in-matching-buffers` that all the result would be displayed in a persistent buffer with the matching strings highlighted along with their complete line and I could simply move to that result and press <kbd>C-o</kbd> to jump to it.

But in Icicle, maybe I'm missing something, I can't do that. The result/completion go away when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>C-g</kbd>. Switching to the `*Completion*` buffer and pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> I get a *user-error* saying

> Minibuffer is not active for completion

How can I get a dedicated buffer which contain the results? And it would be a plus when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> the string(s) which caused that buffer to get a selected, or something similar.

I went through [Persistent Completions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Persistent_Completions) but I found it to be kind of *complex*.

Answer (score 0):

[**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) is mainly about minibuffer completion. It is true that it offers ways to manipulate and navigate sets of things. But yes, this is done using buffer `*Completions*`.

And yes, you can save a set of candidates that are in `*Completions*`, and reuse it later. You can save a set only for the current Emacs session, or you can save it persistently (in a file).

For saving and restoring persistently, you had the right [doc location](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Persistent_Completions).  But to understand that you should first read the more general section about [saving and restoring completions](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Candidate_Sets) in *general* (i.e., whether persistently or just for the current session).

For the current session, you can save a set of candidates to the default variable, or you can specify a variable name.  Use different variables if you want to manipulate different sets of candidates in the same session.

And yes, the idea is a bit complicated at first -- it helps to read a bit of the doc.  But it is not difficult to use in practice, and **Icicles** gives you feedback wrt which candidates have been saved (they are shaded in `*Completions*`.